# Correct format for converting string to R date-time object

Tags: r, datetime

I've a system generated date and time format. It looks something like this, "`2017-04-12-02.29.25.000000`" . I want to convert this format into a standard one so that my system can read this and later on I can convert it into minutes. Someone please help to provide a code in R.

Comment: "2017-04-12-02.29.25.000000" all of these are connected. Please tell a way to at least separate them out into "2017-04-12   02.29.25.000000"

Comment: `as.POSIXct("2017-04-12-02.29.25.000000", "%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", origin="1970-01-01",tz="UTC")`

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure of the format, the `guess_formats` function in `lubridate` is pretty helpful:

```
w <- "2017-04-12-02.29.25.000000"
> lubridate::guess_formats(w, orders = 'YmdHMS')
              YOmdHMS                YmdHMS 
"%Y-%Om-%d-%H.%M.%OS"  "%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%OS"
```

`orders` is the format you want the function to investigate and it outputs the correct representation. If the second entry in the string is the day you can try `YdmHMS`.

The difference in the two formats in the output in the above example is based on formatting of the second entry (always with a leading zero or not). Trying the first format gives:

```
> as.POSIXct(w, format = "%Y-%Om-%d-%H.%M.%OS")
[1] "2017-04-12 02:29:25 EDT"
```

In the `as.POSIXct` call you may specify the timezone `tz` if required.